# TSVN: svn.exe: How to parse $ sign as an element of the argument (path)?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, network-share

I have a hiden share on the server \BBDD\AAA$

and the post-commit hook looks like:

```
"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe" co https://BBDD/svn/Development/ABC -r HEAD "\\BBDD\AAA$\PROD\MFG\" --password xXxXxXxXx
```

svn.exe cannot resolve the path when the $ sign is used. When I use an unhide share for a moment the hook is parsed correctly.

The error code is:

```
post-commit hook, svn: E020024: Error resolving case of "\\BBDD\AAA$\PROD\MFG\"
```

Does anyone know how I can use the $ sign to be parsed by svn.exe

Answer (score 0):

The error you get (`svn: E020024: Error resolving case of`) indicates that the network share is inaccessible by the user account under which you run the command line. The most possible cause is the lack of privileges to the network share. You should double-check access permissions configured on the network share.

VisualSVN Server's service runs under `Network Service` account, by default. This built-in Windows account represents computer's account credentials on the network so you have to provide the COMPUTER account with NTFS and share permissions to the network share.